# How can I merge two rows in a result but not all results?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have the following query:

```
-- Compare current period to historical data
select  Name ,
        avg(TimeProcessing + TimeRendering + TimeDataRetrieval) / 1000  as 'Current Month' ,
        isnull(count(TimeProcessing), 0)                                as 'Sample' ,
        min(l2.[Avg_Exec_Time_Previous_Month])                          as 'Previous Month' ,
        isnull(min(l2.[Executions_Last_Month]), 0)                      as 'Sample' ,
        min(l3.[Avg_Exec_Time_Two_Months_Ago])                          as 'Two Months ago' ,
        isnull(min(l3.[Executions_Two_Months_Ago]), 0)                  as 'Sample'
from    marlin.report_execution_log l
        inner join marlin.report_catalog c on l.ReportID = c.ItemID
        left outer join ( 
                        select    
                            l2.ReportID ,
                            (
                            avg(l2.TimeProcessing + l2.TimeRendering 
                            + l2.TimeDataRetrieval) / 1000 
                            ) as 'Avg_Exec_Time_Previous_Month' ,
                            count(l2.TimeProcessing) as 'Executions_Last_Month'
                        from    
                            marlin.report_execution_log l2
                        where   
                            TimeEnd between dateadd(MONTH, -2, getdate())
                                    and     dateadd(MONTH, -1, getdate())
                        group by  
                            l2.ReportID
                        ) l2 on l.ReportID = l2.ReportID
        left outer join ( 
                        select    
                            l3.ReportID ,
                            (
                            avg(l3.TimeProcessing + l3.TimeRendering + l3.TimeDataRetrieval) / 1000 
                            ) as 'Avg_Exec_Time_Two_Months_Ago' ,
                            count(l3.TimeProcessing) as 'Executions_Two_Months_Ago'
                        from  
                            marlin.report_execution_log l3
                        where 
                            TimeEnd between dateadd(MONTH, -3, getdate())
                                    and     dateadd(MONTH, -2, getdate())
                        group by  
                            l3.ReportID
                        ) l3 on l.ReportID = l3.ReportID
group by    l.ReportID ,
            Name
order by    2 desc
```

Which brings up the following results:

[image: Results]

Unfortunately one our reports changed names throughout the month and subsequently I need to merge these two rows. Is this possible? How can I merge two rows? For example, how could I have the first and second row show additive results using the first rows report name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understood it well you just need a case statement in your select and in your group by.. something like

```
select  case when Name = 'Project1' then 'Project1'
             when Name = 'Project2' then 'Project1'
             else Name
        end as NAME
.......
group by case when Name = 'Project1' then 'Project1'
             when Name = 'Project2' then 'Project1'
             else Name
        end
```

if your case is that now is Project 1 and one month ago was Project 2, you may need to add the date in the case statement (just in case)

```
 select  case when Name = 'Project1' and TimeEnd = getdate()  then 'Project1'
                 when Name = 'Project2' and TimeEnd = dateadd(MONTH, -1, getdate()) then 'Project1'
                 else Name
            end as NAME
    .......
    group by case when Name = 'Project1' and TimeEnd = getdate()  then 'Project1'
                 when Name = 'Project2' and  TimeEnd = dateadd(MONTH, -1, getdate()) then 'Project1'
                 else Name
        end
```

That's the idea.

**Edit.**

I think you have an option if they get repeated but I dont really like it at all

```
SELECT NAME, AVG(Current Month) as Current Month, count(Sample) as Sample, min(Previous Month) as Previous Month, min(Sample2) as Sample2, min(Two Months ago) as Two Months ago,
min(Sample3) as Sample3
FROM
(
select  Name ,
        avg(TimeProcessing + TimeRendering + TimeDataRetrieval) / 1000  as 'Current Month' ,
        isnull(count(TimeProcessing), 0)                                as 'Sample' ,
        min(l2.[Avg_Exec_Time_Previous_Month])                          as 'Previous Month' ,
        isnull(min(l2.[Executions_Last_Month]), 0)                      as 'Sample2' ,
        min(l3.[Avg_Exec_Time_Two_Months_Ago])                          as 'Two Months ago' ,
        isnull(min(l3.[Executions_Two_Months_Ago]), 0)                  as 'Sample3'
from    marlin.report_execution_log l
        inner join marlin.report_catalog c on l.ReportID = c.ItemID
        left outer join ( 
                        select    
                            l2.ReportID ,
                            (
                            avg(l2.TimeProcessing + l2.TimeRendering 
                            + l2.TimeDataRetrieval) / 1000 
                            ) as 'Avg_Exec_Time_Previous_Month' ,
                            count(l2.TimeProcessing) as 'Executions_Last_Month'
                        from    
                            marlin.report_execution_log l2
                        where   
                            TimeEnd between dateadd(MONTH, -2, getdate())
                                    and     dateadd(MONTH, -1, getdate())
                        group by  
                            l2.ReportID
                        ) l2 on l.ReportID = l2.ReportID
        left outer join ( 
                        select    
                            l3.ReportID ,
                            (
                            avg(l3.TimeProcessing + l3.TimeRendering + l3.TimeDataRetrieval) / 1000 
                            ) as 'Avg_Exec_Time_Two_Months_Ago' ,
                            count(l3.TimeProcessing) as 'Executions_Two_Months_Ago'
                        from  
                            marlin.report_execution_log l3
                        where 
                            TimeEnd between dateadd(MONTH, -3, getdate())
                                    and     dateadd(MONTH, -2, getdate())
                        group by  
                            l3.ReportID
                        ) l3 on l.ReportID = l3.ReportID
group by    l.ReportID ,
            Name
)
group by  Name
order by    2 desc
```

Comment: This sets me on the right path - hadn't considered that. Thank-you very much.